# Save byte pointer to a file

Tags: c++, linux, sdk

I'm using ProtonSDK (www.protonsdk.com)

Im trying to use this function

```
byte *pData = GetFileManager()->Get("texturefile.rttex", &fileSizeBytes, true, true);
```

I want to save the output to a file (Decompressed RTPACK) but it doesn't want to.

I am fairly new to C++ but I have a background with PHP

Comment: What error message do you get exactly? How does it not work?

Comment: Saving a pointer to permanent storage is usually a waste of time. You will almost certainly not be allocated the same memory location the next time around, and if you did, the data would almost certainly not be there. Are you perhaps wanting to save the data being pointed at?

Comment: I want to save the decompressed data into a file

Comment: Lubomir, the pointer is empty if(!pData)

Comment: That protonsdk website is annoying. Where the hell are the API docs? I like to learn as I go, but this is just stupid!

Comment: I'm also confused about it

Answer (score 0):

You can write it to a file with the C++ standard library.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Or the C standard library.

Write data pData is pointing to.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Proton SDK header */
/* header with byte type (not part of C standard library) */

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        int fileSizeBytes;
        FILE* fp;

        byte *pData = GetFileManager()->Get(GetSavePath()+"test.txt", &fileSizeBytes, true);

        fp = fopen("put_filename_here", "w");
        if(fp == NULL) {
                fprintf("Cannot open file!\n");
                exit(-1);
        }
        fwrite(pData, fileSizeBytes, sizeof(byte), fp);
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
}
```

Write pData itself to the file.
    `fwrite(&pData, 1, sizeof(pData), fp);`

Comment: pData is empty when i checked if its null

Comment: Did you check the documentation for the GetFileManager()?  Sounds like it can't open the file.

Comment: It opens the file. It will print an error indicating that the file cannot be opened.

Comment: GetFileManager is not part of the Standard Library.  Is it part of Proton SDK?

Comment: Yes it is part of ProtonSDK. from the SVN repo it is declared in shared/FileSystem/FileManager.h

Comment: *It will print an error indicating that the file cannot be opened.* what is *it*? To where does *it* print this message?

Comment: Did you check what GetSavePath() is returning?  Maybe the path is at a location with restricted permissions.

Comment: LogError("Proton FileManager says can't open %s", fileName.c_str());
LogError is just a printf with a logging function

Comment: Jeremiah, I'm trying to read the decompressed data
Then save it to a file.
pData is NULL when im trying to get the data

Comment: The documentation (http://www.rtsoft.com/wiki/doku.php?id=proton:filemanager) is not very clear on what each parameter does.  I think the last parameter is for prepend.  Try making it `false` and see what happens.

Comment: first is for filepath. Second is for file size. third is for adding the path of the executable to the filepath (The directory) the fourth is for decompressing the rttex files (AutoDecompress)

Comment: I don't know what else to say without debugging the code myself. Are you using a debugger?

Comment: I dont. I just checked the code of protonsdk since its Open source

Comment: Do you know where **filepath** is?  i.e. do you know what `GetSavePath()` "Not `GetFileManager()`" is returning?

Comment: Actually i dont use GetSavePath() I specify the file path using argv[1]
Files are ok. the function isnt returning any data.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what the problem is.  `argv[1]` is of `char *` type and the first argument of `GetFileManager()->Get()` is of `std::string` type. Try `GetFileManager()->Get(std::string(argv[1]), &fileSizeBytes, true)` to convert the `char *` to `std::string`.  Also don't forget the header `#include <string>`

Comment: using argv[1] has no problems. it reads the file. it will show an error if the file cant be read or if it doesnt exist.
I tried using a string (filename) pData is still null
Its supposed to return decompressed data according to proton/shared/FileSystem/FileManager.cpp

Comment: I'm checking out the Source Code right now with svn. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Can you give me the exact line of code for your `GetFileManager()`?

Comment: byte *pData = GetFileManager()->Get("texture.rttex", &fileSizeBytes, true, true);

Comment: What does `GetBaseAppPath()` return?  Because that is what the path is if the third argument of `GetFileManager()->Get()` is `true`

Comment: I would try `printf("GetBaseAppPath() = \"%s\"\n", GetBaseAppPath().c_str());` you may need to include `PlatformEnums.h`

Comment: It automatically included it in the SDK
BaseAppPath returns the current directory of the executable file